# How to transfer pairing key info from one Central to another using Bluez?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I currently have a scenario where I have 3 raspberry pis. One peripheral and two centrals(acting as two APs in the same enterprise network). The requirement is when the peripheral moves from Central 1 to another, it should be able to pair with the Central 2 without the need for the pass code to be entered.  For this I have configured both the Centrals to have the same bluetooth MAC address. I am also manually copying the /var/lib/bluetooth/<central-mac-address>/<peripheral-mac-address>/**info** which has the CSRK, Remote Signature Keys and so on to Central 2. But inspite of that, peripheral is not able to connect to Central 2 without the pass code.

Is there a way to implement this functionality in pi using bluez?

Comment: Are you bonding the devices as well or are you only pairing? Without bonding you should be asked for the passcode even if you return to central 1 again, right?

Comment: Yes, I am bonding, I am able to re-connect to Central 1 without the passcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working after restarting the bluetooth service.
**sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service**.

Comment: Did you transfer the IRK as well or were you able to bond without it?